# Using gravity forms with an asynchronous site

Tags: angularjs, ajax, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a wordpress site using angular to handle ajaxed page loads. When loading a page directly, the gravity forms load as expected. If you load from a non grav forms page then navigate to one with a form, you get nothing.

This may have something to do with the scripts grav forms embeds below the forms. So I am wondering if there is a way to init a form after being loaded in via ajax.

I can use some html, jquery magic to fetch the form via ajax after page load using this in functions.php:

```
gravity_form_enqueue_scripts( $form_id, true );
echo gravity_form($form_id, false, false, false, null, true, 12, true);
```

When I inject the results into the DOM I just get this console error:

```
gformInitSpinner is not defined
```

and even if I target the new html and show the form, which comes through as html, I get a massively malformed form that doesn't work. Clearly because the scripts don't get evaluated and that js error blocks it anyhow.

So does anyone know if there is a way to make gravity forms work with an asynchronous site? Or if you can load a functional form using ajax?

I am not able to fill the enqueue system with gravity_form_enqueue_scripts since there could be any number of forms made at any time. That's not a practical solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, no thanks to the gravity forms development team and the entire internet, we have a solution for all of us tasked with what seems like an obvious use of a very commonly used plugin...

First off, set up your functions.php file so it can handle this:

```
// filter the Gravity Forms button type
add_filter( 'gform_submit_button', 'form_submit_button', 10, 2 );
function form_submit_button( $button, $form ) {
    return "<button class='btn btn-green' type='submit' id='gform_submit_button_{$form['id']}'>Submit</button>";
}

// Hook up the AJAX actions
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_gf_button_get_form', 'gform_ajax_get_form' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_gf_button_get_form', 'gform_ajax_get_form' );

// Add the "button" action to the gravityforms shortcode
// e.g. [gravityforms action="button" id=1 text="button text"]
add_filter( 'gform_shortcode_form', 'gform_shortcode', 10, 3 );

function gform_shortcode( $shortcode_string, $attributes, $content )
{
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => 0,
        'text' => 'Show me the form!',
    ), $attributes );

    $form_id = absint( $a['id'] );

    if ( $form_id < 1 ) {
        return 'Missing the ID attribute.';
    }

    $ajax_url = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );

    $html = sprintf('<div ng-controller="GavityFormController as garvityFormCtrl" ng-init="init(\'%s\', \'%s\')"><div class="gform_container" ng-include="form"></div></div>', $form_id, $ajax_url);

    return $html;
}

function gform_ajax_get_form(){
    $form_id = isset( $_GET['form_id'] ) ? absint( $_GET['form_id'] ) : 0;
    $form = gravity_form($form_id, false, false, false, false, true, 0, false);

    $form = str_replace('text/javascript', 'text/ng-javascript', $form);
    $form = str_replace('<script ', '<script lazy-js ', $form);

    echo $form;

    die();
}

add_filter("wp_footer", "init_gf_scripts");
function init_gf_scripts() {
    global $wpdb;

    //obviously change this if your prefix is different
    $sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `wp_rg_form` WHERE `is_active` = 1 AND `is_trash` = 0";
    $res = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    foreach($res AS $r)
    {
        gravity_form_enqueue_scripts( $r->id, true );
    }
}
```

Next step can vary depending on how you set up your main js file. The necessary points being below. There's usually quite a bit more but hopefully you get the idea.

```
(function(){
    require('./directives/forms/form');

    var util = require('./util');

    var app = angular.module('yourapp', [
        'yourapp-form',
    ])...
```

util.js ... probably a common file. I'm not sure if it really has anything to do with the actual problem but it is required by the form components so here you go:

```
module.exports = (function() {
    var api = {
        isMobileOrSmaller: function () {
            return $(window).width() < 681
        },
        findByProp: function (data, value, prop) {
            prop = prop || 'id';
            return $.grep(data, function(e){ return e[prop] == value; });
        },
        getIndexOf: function (collection, value, prop) {
            prop = prop || 'id';
            return collection.map(function (e) { return e[prop] }).indexOf(value);
        },
        roundTo: function (value, to) {
            to = to || 10;
            return Math.floor(value/to) * to;
        },
        debounce: function(func, wait, immediate) {
            var timeout;
            return function() {
                var context = this, args = arguments;
                var later = function() {
                    timeout = null;
                    if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
                };
                var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
                if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
            };
        },
        getScrollbarWidth: function () {
            return $(window).width();// - $('#siteBody > div').width();
        },
        getRandomInt: function (min, max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        }
    };

    return api;
})();
```

And the form directives...

/directives/forms/form.js

```
module.exports = (function() {
    var api = {};

    var form = angular.module('yourapp-form', [
    ]).directive('lazyJs', [function () {
        return {
            restricted: 'A',
            link: function (scope, element) {
                var code = element.text();
                var tmpFunc = new Function(code);

                scope.$on('GavityFormController::includeContentLoaded', function () {
                    tmpFunc();

                    if(window['gformInitDatepicker']) {
                        gformInitDatepicker();
                    }

                    if (window['gformInitPriceFields']) {
                        gformInitPriceFields();
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }]).controller('GavityFormController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$element', '$http', function ($scope, $rootScope, $element, $http) {
        var panel = this,
            formId = 0; 

        $scope.form = '';
        $scope.init = function (id, url) {
            formId = id;
            $scope.form = url + '?action=gf_button_get_form&form_id=' + id
        }

        $scope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function(e, src){
            if ($('#gform_wrapper_' + formId).length > 0) {
                $scope.$broadcast('GavityFormController::includeContentLoaded');
            }
        });
    }]);

    //registerring componenets
    var radio = require ('./radio');
    radio.register(form);

    var select = require ('./select');
    select.register(form);

    var text = require ('./text');
    text.register(form);

    var check = require ('./check');
    check.register(form);

    var textarea = require('./textarea');
    textarea.register(form);

    api.form = form;


    return api;
})();
```

and these are all the required form component files:

radio.js:

```
module.exports = (function() {
    var api = {};

    api.register = function (form) {
        form.directive('myappRadio', function(){
            return {
                restricted: 'E',
                transclude: true,
                replace: true,
                scope: {
                    model: '=model'
                },
                template: function ($element, $attrs) {
                    return '<div class="ipt ipt-radio"> \
                                <div  ng-transclude></div> \
                                <label for="' + $attrs.for + '">' + $attrs.label + '</label> \
                            </div>';

                }
            }
        });
    }


    return api;
})();
```

select.js:

```
var util = require('./../../util');

module.exports = (function() {
    var api = {};

    api.register = function (form) {
        form.directive('select', ['$timeout', function($timeout){
            return {
                restricted: 'E',
                link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        Selectize.define('input_modify', function(options) {
                            var self = this;

                            this.setup = (function() {
                                var original = self.setup;
                                return function() {
                                    original.apply(this, arguments);

                                    this.$control.find('input').attr('id', '');
                                };
                            })();
                        });

                        $($element).selectize({
                            plugins: ['remove_button', 'input_modify']
                        });
                    }, 10);
                }
            }
        }])
    }


    return api;
})();
```

text.js

```
module.exports = (function() {
    var api = {};

    api.register = function (form) {

        form.directive('myapptext', function(){
            return {
                restricted: 'E',
                scope: {
                    model: '=model',
                    ngrequired: '='
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
                    var panel = this;

                    scope.isActive = scope.model !== '';
                    scope.required = false;

                    if (attrs.required === "")
                        scope.required = true;

                    if (typeof scope.ngrequired !== "undefined")
                        scope.required = scope.ngrequired;

                    scope.onEnter = function () {
                        scope.isActive = true;
                    }

                    scope.onLeave = function () {
                        if (scope.model == '' || typeof scope.model == 'undefined'){
                            scope.isActive = false;
                        }
                    }

                    scope.$watch('ngrequired', function(value){
                        scope.required = scope.ngrequired;
                    });
                },
                template: function (element, attr) {
                    var id = attr.id || 'frm-' + attr.name,
                        type = attr.type || 'text';
                        value = attr.value || '';
                    return '<div class="ipt-text-wrappper" ng-class="{\'m-active\': isActive}"> \
                                <input ng-required="required" ng-focus="onEnter()" ng-blur="onLeave()" ng-model="model" id="' + id + '" type="' + type + '" name="' + attr.name + '" value="' + value + '" class="ipt ipt-text"> \
                                <label ng-click="onEnter()" for="' + id + '">' + attr.label + '</label> \
                            </div>';
                }
            }
        });
    }


    return api;
})();
```

check.js:

```
module.exports = (function() {
    var api = {};

    api.register = function (form) {
        form.directive('myappCheck', function(){
            return {
                restricted: 'E',
                transclude: true,
                replace: true,
                scope: {
                    model: '=model'
                },
                template: function ($element, $attrs) {
                    return '<div class="ipt ipt-radio"> \
                                <div  ng-transclude></div> \
                                <label for="' + $attrs.for + '">' + $attrs.label + '</label> \
                            </div>';

                }
            }
        });
    }


    return api;
})();
```

textarea.js:

```
module.exports = (function() {
    var api = {};

    api.register = function (form) {
        form.directive('myapptextarea', function(){
            return {
                restricted: 'E',
                scope: {
                    model: '=model',
                    ngrequired: '='
                },
                link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
                    var panel = this;

                    scope.isActive = scope.model !== '';
                    scope.required = false;

                    if (attrs.required === "")
                        scope.required = true;

                    if (typeof scope.ngrequired !== "undefined")
                        scope.required = scope.ngrequired;

                    scope.onEnter = function () {
                        scope.isActive = true;
                    }

                    scope.onLeave = function () {
                        if (scope.model == '' || typeof scope.model == 'undefined'){
                            scope.isActive = false;
                        }
                    }

                    scope.$watch('ngrequired', function(value){
                        scope.required = scope.ngrequired;
                    });
                },
                template: function (element, attr) {
                    var id = attr.id || 'frm-' + attr.name,
                        value = attr.value || '';
                    return '<div class="ipt-text-wrappper" ng-class="{\'m-active\': isActive}"> \
                                <textarea ng-required="required" ng-focus="onEnter()" ng-blur="onLeave()" ng-model="model" id="' + id + '" name="' + attr.name + '" class="ipt ipt-textarea">' + value + '</textarea> \
                                <label ng-click="onEnter()" for="' + id + '">' + attr.label + '</label> \
                            </div>';
                }
            }
        });
    }


    return api;
})();
```

And that's it. Personally I invoke this in php by calling gravity_form function:

```
<?php echo gravity_form(1, false, false, false, '', true, 12); ?>
```

But I assume that a basic embedded form in the WYSIWYG would work also.

I didn't write this myself so I am not sure if I could answer questions, but if you have them feel free to ask

Comment: EXPLAIN YOUR DOWNVOTE! THIS WORKS AND I GOT NO SUPPORT FROM GRAV FORMS! What, you don't like it when people call out popular products when they FAIL their PAYING customers? Well, go on! Say why you think others who have to put grav forms on a client's site shouldn't have a solution that is not documented anywhere else... I'd love to hear it

Comment: I don't see where you specify what was wrong. Instead i see a bunch of code dumps with no explanation of how they fix the given problem, why they are needed, or what they do. Not useful. It's more of a tutorial than an answer, but without explanation.

Comment: You don't understand "So does anyone know if there is a way to make gravity forms work with an asynchronous site? Or if you can load a functional form using ajax?" - Uh... I answered MY OWN QUESTION with the CODE I USED TO MAKE IT WORK WITH AN ASYNCHRONOUS SITE as indicated by basically everything on the page. Believe me, I am enraged completely by gravity form's lack of a response and I am not alone. Anyone on earth needing to use gravity forms with angular will not have a hard time piecing this together

Comment: And if they find it useful they can cast their vote. :)

Comment: And seriously, NOT USEFUL?! I had the damn decency to come back and answer the question after I got no response from anyone anywhere. A co-worker happened to have had to solve this once upon a time. I could have left it in the darkness and shared it with nobody. F, man. Downvote the idiot that answers with "did you try googling" - and if you tried the code above and it straight up don't work then sure, downvote all day long. Otherwise just keep on moving